# Integrate Paytm gateway or api for transfer money one wallet to another wallet?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Can we integrate Paytm gateway or api for transfer money one wallet to another wallet? If Yes so please give me guild lines or link how to I integrate into my project. (My project configuration is Asp.net core for Web API and Client side for Angular).

Answer (score 0):

Paytm does not provide api to transfer money from one wallet to other wallet. It can be done only from business wallet.